# How to list keybinding for a particular keymap (evil-mode)?

Tags: evil, keymap

I am trying out [`evil-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil), and it seems promising. Now I would like to get an overview of the keybindings introduced in `evil-normal-state-map`. If I type `C-h v RET evil-normal-state-map` I get:

```
Value: (keymap
 (164 . evil-end-of-line)
 (mouse-2 . mouse-yank-primary)
 (18 . redo)
 (117 . undo)
 (remap keymap
        (yank-pop . evil-paste-pop)
        (cua-paste-pop . evil-paste-pop))
 (escape . evil-force-normal-state)
 (127 . evil-backward-char)
 (90 keymap
     (81 . evil-quit)
     (90 . evil-save-modified-and-close))
 (62 . evil-shift-right)
 (60 . evil-shift-left)
 (61 . evil-indent)
 (126 . evil-invert-char)
 (34 . evil-use-register)
 (64 . evil-execute-macro)
 (46 . evil-repeat)
 (27 keymap
     (46 . evil-repeat-pop-next))
 (67108910 . evil-repeat-pop)
 (20 . pop-tag-mark)
 (16 . evil-paste-pop)
 (14 . evil-paste-pop-next)
 (122 keymap
      (61 . ispell-word)
      (109 . evil-close-folds)
      (114 . evil-open-folds)
      (97 . evil-toggle-fold)
      (99 . evil-close-fold)
      (79 . evil-open-fold-rec)
      (111 . evil-open-fold))
 (103 keymap
      (44 . goto-last-change-reverse)
      (59 . goto-last-change)
      (126 . evil-invert-case)
      (63 . evil-rot13)
      (70 . evil-find-file-at-point-with-line)
      (102 . find-file-at-point)
      (85 . evil-upcase)
      (117 . evil-downcase)
      (119 . evil-fill)
      (113 . evil-fill-and-move)
      (74 . evil-join-whitespace)
      (105 . evil-insert-resume)
      (97 . what-cursor-position)
      (56 . what-cursor-position)
      (38 . evil-ex-repeat-global-substitute))
 (38 . evil-ex-repeat-substitute)
 (89 . evil-yank-line)
 (121 . evil-yank)
 (deletechar . evil-delete-char)
 (88 . evil-delete-backward-char)
 (120 . evil-delete-char)
 (83 . evil-change-whole-line)
 (115 . evil-substitute)
 (82 . evil-replace-state)
 (114 . evil-replace)
 (113 . evil-record-macro)
 (80 . evil-paste-before)
 (112 . evil-paste-after)
 (79 . evil-open-above)
 (111 . evil-open-below)
 (109 . evil-set-marker)
 (74 . evil-join)
 (73 . evil-insert-line)
 (insertchar . evil-insert)
 (insert . evil-insert)
 (105 . evil-insert)
 (68 . evil-delete-line)
 (100 . evil-delete)
 (67 . evil-change-line)
 (99 . evil-change)
 (65 . evil-append-line)
 (97 . evil-append))
```

How can I transform this into human-readable form? It would be nice if I could have the table in the format given by `describe-mode`, e.g.:

```
key             binding
---             -------

C-c             Prefix Command
C-d             elisp-edebug
  (that binding is currently shadowed by another mode)
ESC             Prefix Command
DEL             backward-delete-char-untabify

....
```

Comment: You can try `C-h b` instead, and look for the sections called `evil-normal-state-minor-mode`, `evil-motion-state-minor-mode` and (perhaps) their local versions.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480173/show-keys-in-emacs-keymap-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this in vanilla Emacs without effective writing your own code, but the function `describe-keymap` (`C-h M-k`) in the [help-fns+.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HelpPlus) package does exactly this.

> `describe-keymap` (`C-h M-k`) – Describe the bindings in a keymap. Enter the keymap variable (e.g., `ctl-x-map`) using completion. (Non-interactively, the argument can be a keymap itself or a keymap variable.)

Comment: If I try `C-h M-k evil-motion-state-map` it lists some bindings starting with `<remap>`. For example: `<remap> <avy-goto-char>         evil-avy-goto-char`. How to print the actual key binding in this case?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I don't know any pre-existing way to have that for the entire `describe-keymap` output, but if you just want to check a single remapped keybinding, you could just do the usual `C-h f avy-goto-char`, and the help output should say something like "Its keys are remapped to '...'. Without this remapping, it would be bound to ...." (replace ... with the appropriate functions).

Answer (score 1):

Beside `describe-keymap` function `which-key-dump-bindings` can be useful what key-bindings my modes provides.

`which-key-dump-bindings` answers the question **Which key bindings I can use in this buffer?**. Function will allow you understand which `minor`, `major` modes keys and global key bindings are active and can be used.

Usage: 
Function will ask for prefix:

If you provide:

`Directly pressing enter` will show you every possible keys in this buffer.

`C-x` it's same as `ctl-x-map`

`C-x 4` is equal to `ctl-x-4-map`